# Delete a div within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below form I am trying to delete the entire div `addedtrans` and then add a button near  the button `nonpayment`. Below is the HTML and the jQuery function in question:

```
<form action="tvbill.php" method="GET" name="tvbillform">
<table class="persontitle">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="button" id="cancelCable" name="cancelCable" value="Cancel Cable">
            <input type="submit" class="button" id="nonpayment" name="nonpayment" value="Non-Payment">                  
        </td>     
    </tr>   
</table>

<div id="addtransaction">
    <div class="addedtrans">
        <div>
            <label class="labeltitle">Complete Transaction</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Complete Transaction" id="completecreditrx" name="completecreditrx" class="buttonlarge buttonmargin">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel Transaction" id="cancelcreditrx" name="cancelcreditrx" class="buttonlarge">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="billingdate" class="labeltitle">Transaction Date:
                <input type="text" id="billingdate" name="billingdate" class="datepick hasDatepicker">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="cabletransamt" class="labeltitle">Transaction Amount
                <input type="text" id="cabletransamt" name="cabletransamt" class="automoney">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="cabletranstype" class="labeltitle">Transaction Type
                <select id="cabletranstype" name="cabletranstype">
                    <option value="7">choice one</option>
                    <option value="10">Credit</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){
    $("#cancelcreditrx").click(function(){
        var addbutton = $("<input>").attr('type','button').attr('id','addTrx').attr('name','addTrx').attr('value','Add Cable Transaction').addClass("buttonlarge");
        $(".addedtrans").remove();
        $("#nonpayment").append(addbutton);   
    })
})
```

Comment: i think want this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lyvkz0ag/1/ you are appending to a button you can append it to a td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/billjohnston4/c9rd3jpw/

You are looking for `.after()`, `.append()` only works when adding to a parent element.

```
$(function () {
    $("#cancelcreditrx").click(function () {
        var addbutton = $("<input>", {
            'type': 'button',
            'id': 'addTrx',
            'name': 'addTrx',
            'value': 'Add Cable Transaction',
            'class': 'buttonlarge'
        });
        $(".addedtrans").remove();
        $("#nonpayment").after(addbutton);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$(".addedtrans").hide();` since you're not wanting to completely remove it from the DOM.

Instead of appending though, you'll be using `$".addedtrans").show();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hwn8c3bx/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("#cancelcreditrx").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".addedtrans").remove();
        $("#nonpayment").after('<input type="button" id="addTrx" name="addTrx" value="Add Cable Transaction" class="buttonlarge">'); 
    });
});
```

using [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) you can append an element, after the selected set of elements.

Answer (score 0):

you are appending to a button you can append it to a `td` instead

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/Lyvkz0ag/1/)

```
$(".persontitle td").append(addbutton);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't append the addButton to an input type='submit'. To you want to put it in the td ?

```
$("#cancelcreditrx").click(function(){
        var addbutton = $("<input>").attr('type','button').attr('id','addTrx').attr('name','addTrx').attr('value','Add Cable Transaction').addClass("buttonlarge");
        $(".addedtrans").remove();
        $(".persontitle tr td").append(addbutton);   
    });
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/911/)

Comment: What does `<input type="submit" class="button" id="nonpayment" name="nonpayment" value="Non-Payment">` mean then?

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: i don't have enought reputation to comment

Comment: All right folks now you can Upvote him as has edited his answer and is the correct answer too. Or you guys just shoo away after downvoting, no matter if SO has altered his answer or not?